# Vuejs Migration 1x to 2x Compile Function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

1x Code: 
It is working.

```
this.$compile(this.$els.ajaxcontent);
```

2x Migration:

```
this.$compile(this.$refs.ajaxcontent);
// Error: $compile function not found.

Vue.compile(this.$refs.ajaxcontent);
// Error: template.trim not a function.

Vue.compile($('#ajaxContent').get(0));
// Error: template.trim not a function.
```

Compile Documentation : http://vuejs.org/api/#Vue-compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
var tmp = Vue.extend({ 
    template: 'Content'
})
new tmp().$mount(' id or refs ')
```

Answer (score 0):

`Vue.compile` needs a String. I dont know how exactly how to do it with jquery but try

`Vue.compile(document.getElementById('ajaxContent').innerHTML)`